# "What ... will" v.s. "What will..."

Tags: sentence-structure, interrogatives

Compare the following pair of sentences:

> What Chinese Tariffs Targeting American Crops Will Mean For Farmers
>
> What will Chinese tariffs targeting American crops mean for farmers?

Why does the former conveys an explanatory sense, as it is normally used as a title in articles to elaborate on the topic, while the latter is interrogative? Please explain in grammatical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions with pronouns (what, which...) take a *verb* immediately after it to *form a question.*

> What will he charge for his services?

This sentence *without* a question mark will be considered incorrect.

On the other hand, if the sentence is declarative, you don't write verb after 'what.'

> I don't know *what he will* charge for his services **NOT** I don't know *what will he* charge for his services.

As far as titles are concerned, they are called *[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese),* and are written by taking some liberty in grammar rules.

Comment: The first sentence mentioned in my question doesn't seem to be declarative though. I think it is rather a shortened statement that needs further modification of additional clauses to form an independent one, if you see what I mean.

Comment: For example, `What Chinese tariffs targeting American crops will mean for farmers is depressing.`

Comment: @skygate - You are correct that it's not a complete sentence.  It would need a main verb to be a complete sentence.  But headlines in English are often not written in complete sentences: look up the word *headlinese* for a description of the grammar used there.